# change non-zero padded hour and minute into 24hr time

Tags: date, timestamps, csv

I have data that I need to change before running it through the pandas library in python.

It is currently in a format that stores **midnight values as 2400** and that should be **changed to 0000**. The format also does not pad either hour nor minute, and I think I need to do so in order to convert the 2 parameters into a **desired zero padded 2400hr (0000-2359)** format.

Now that's the easy part!

The hard part is that each time it rolls over from 2359 to 0000 it should **also change the date** (which is in 'dayoftheyear' format, which actually makes it easier I assume, i.e.: %j +1, aside from Dec 31).

So here is a sample of my data (last 2 columns are non-date values stored) at a day's rollover (it is a csv file, but I am showing it with a single space to delimit for visual clarity):

```
1,2014,361,2340,0,0
1,2014,361,2341,0,0
1,2014,361,2342,0,0
1,2014,361,2343,0,0
1,2014,361,2344,0,0
1,2014,361,2345,0,0
1,2014,361,2346,0,0
1,2014,361,2347,0,0
1,2014,361,2348,0,0
1,2014,361,2349,0,0
1,2014,361,2350,0,0
1,2014,361,2351,0,0
1,2014,361,2352,0,0
1,2014,361,2353,0,0
1,2014,361,2354,0,0
1,2014,361,2355,0,0
1,2014,361,2356,0,0
1,2014,361,2357,0,0
1,2014,361,2358,0,0
1,2014,361,2359,0,0
1,2014,361,2400,0,0
24,2014,361,2400,12.34
1,2014,365,2359,0,9
1,2014,365,2400,089.343,3
1,2015,1,1,234,456
1,2015,1,2,090,99
1,2015,365,2359,0,0
1,2015,365,2400,xx,xxx
1,2016,1,1,0,0
1,2016,1,2,0,0
1,2016,1,3,0,0
```

I assume the solution is a bunch of sed/awk nested in a for loop, but i'll leave that up to you code ninjas. Thanks in advance.

**Ok, here is the same question but extended to include the "what if" once the new year rolls around.** So I assume that the $2 column will get incremented come 365 to 366, and this is obviously not desirable.

How do I then extend the same incrementing/formatting to include a roll over come 366 to increment the year by 1?

I am going to take a blind stab at it:

```
#!/bin/bash


filename="${1/.dat/_prepped.dat}"

awk '/^1/{print $0}' $1  |cut -d "," -f2,3,4,5,6 |

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
$3 == "2400" {$2 = $2 + 1; $3 = 0}
$2 == "366" {$1 = $1 + 1; $2 = 1}
{ $3 = sprintf("%04i", $3) }
1' >$filename
```

I took a stab at integrating everything into a script that i feed the raw data (ex: home.dat) into in order to output the file (ex: home_prepped.dat).

Results of above data running through above script:

```
2014,361,2340,0,0
2014,361,2341,0,0
2014,361,2342,0,0
2014,361,2343,0,0
2014,361,2344,0,0
2014,361,2345,0,0
2014,361,2346,0,0
2014,361,2347,0,0
2014,361,2348,0,0
2014,361,2349,0,0
2014,361,2350,0,0
2014,361,2351,0,0
2014,361,2352,0,0
2014,361,2353,0,0
2014,361,2354,0,0
2014,361,2355,0,0
2014,361,2356,0,0
2014,361,2357,0,0
2014,361,2358,0,0
2014,361,2359,0,0
2014,362,0000,0,0
2014,365,2359,0,9
2015,1,0000,089.343,3
2015,1,0001,234,456
2015,1,0002,090,99
2015,365,2359,0,0
2016,1,0000,xx,xxx
2016,1,0001,0,0
2016,1,0002,0,0
2016,1,0003,0,0
```

Comment: woohoo, it worked! I made a couple of fake rows that were 2014,365,2359,0,0 and 2014,365,2400,0,0 and they both rolled over and updated the year/day column as desired. I am very stoked, and want to thank you for your help! Now up vote this question so I can enough reputation to do the same :)

Comment: It looks like you made it there, so that's this question dealt to, but I have a follow-up for your own consideration: what about 2016?

Comment: You need to put the pattern `$3 == 2400` and the corresponding action `{$2 = ...` on the same line - otherwise the pattern triggers the default action (printing) and the action is run unconditionally.

Comment: Awk has regular variables that you can use to maintain state between records. I don't think I understand the use case any more though.

Comment: All good, ran some tests and i think it's working as desired. I will edit to illustrate before/after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` does all of this by itself. [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-sprintf_0028_0029-function-1) does the formatting, ordinary patterns and assignments do the rest.

```awk
$3 == "2400" {$2 = $2 + 1; $3 = 0}
{ $3 = sprintf("%04i", $3) }
1
```

If you put that into `dates.awk` and then run your sample data through:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, -f dates.awk < data
```

then you will get:

```
...
2014,344,2359,0,0
2014,345,0000,0,0
2014,345,0001,0,0
...
```

The first line of the script checks whether the third field is "2400" using an [expression pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-expressions_002c-as-patterns) and [zeros and increments](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Assignment-Ops) appropriately. The second pads the field to four digits with [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-sprintf_0028_0029-function-1). The last ensures the line is printed.

You can squash that all into a single line to give a script to `awk` on the command line, and also put the field separators into the body by prepending `{FS=OFS=","}`.

You can deal with year rollover yourself; you should be able to pattern it on the above easily, but making the effort yourself will do you good.

Comment: great scot, awk is awesome! Though I haven't quite figured out the -vOFS yet (working on it). I appreciate the descriptions too, as I learn by illustrated example and this helps me out a lot more than struggling on my own. Truly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [`-v VAR=value` is the option for predefining a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_002dv-option) (just like setting it in the body). [`OFS` is the output field separator variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-OFS-variable-1). `-vOFS=,` sets the output separator to a comma, rather than the default (space), so that what you get out is still CSV.

Comment: I am editing my question to extend it a bit to include the inevitable 'what to do come new year' question. I figure I should keep the question in this thread as asking it in another seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

So if third field is equal to `2400` you want to change it to `0000` and increase second field by one? Try `awk` then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$3==2400{$2++;$3="0000"}1'
```

Comment: very nice one-liner Jimmyj, cheers :)